# Store expression in a variable in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given that [IN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177682.aspx) accepts arguments of the format `(subquery | expression [ ,...n ])` can an expression be stored in a variable for re-use?

For example (warning; this is contrived):

```
declare @expression ?expression_type?
declare @test int

set @expression = (44, 132, 133, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170)
set @test = 44

if @test in @expression begin
    -- do something
end

if @test not in @expression begin
    -- do something else
end
```

I'm trying to keep code maintainable by not duplicating the expression. However, the target of this is a function which can be called many times so I don't want to resort to storing these IDs in a table (permanent or temporary) as it would result in unnecessary reads.

Comment: Maybe you will want to look at dynamic sql?

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` based on the link provided

Comment: @Bobby Is that the only way to achieve this? I wondered if there were perhaps any language constructs which would support this?

Comment: Can't you add a column to the table where the IDs live to indicate which IDs your interested in? Don't worry about "unnecessary reads", they belong in a table at the least.

Comment: You can't store multiple values in a single variable. This is no different than any other programming language. In other languages you would use an array. sql server does not have an array datatype because it has tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a table variable will handle this nicely.

```
declare @expression table (value INT)
declare @test int

insert into @expression (value) values (44), (132), (133), (166), (167), (168), (169), (170)
set @test = 44

if @test in (select value from @expression) begin
-- do something
end

if @test not in (select value from @expression) begin
-- do something else
end
```

Comment: This does solve the maintainability problem, but performance does suffer with this, even though the table is in memory. It's not as quick as a raw expression

Comment: If your "expression" list is so long that it suffers from performance degradation in the IF expressions, then you've got bigger problems than code maintainability.

Comment: 2 lists, one with 10 integers the other with 37. Not huge numbers, the performance difference is noticeable due to the amount of times the function is called.

Comment: Maybe you should declare a bit variable @IsInList, and run the comparison only once. Then base all your IF statements on the variable value (0 or 1).

Comment: Yeah I've stuck with the expression approach but managed to restructure the control statements so that each expression is only declared once, I'll mark this as the answer as it solves the general case for this question